# Find the equation relating $x$ and $y$ corresponding to the parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find an equation relating $x$ and $y$ corresponding to the parametric equations

$$x=\dfrac {3t}{(1+t^3) 
}\\y=\dfrac {6t^2}{(1+t^3)}$$
Where $t \ne −1$

by eliminating the variable $t$ and expressing the relation between $x$ and $y$ in the form
$P(x,y)=0$,
where $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ such that the coefficient of $x^3$ is $216$.

Answer:
eqt$=0$

What is the equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE , did you try something  ?

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\dfrac {3t}{(1+t^3) 
},y=\dfrac {(6t^2)}{(1+t^3)}\\\frac yx=\dfrac{\dfrac {(6t^2)}{(1+t^3)}}{\dfrac {3t}{(1+t^3) 
}}=2t$$ so you can find $t$ and put $t$ in one of relations

can you take over ?
final hint
$$t=\frac y{2x}\to \\
x=\dfrac {3t}{(1+t^3)}\to x= \dfrac {3\frac y{2x}}{(1+(\frac y{2x})^3)}$$